# Exception handling in test class. How to write the test class for the following exception handling code?

Tags: unit-test, exception

```
 public static void handleExceptions(Exception e){
        String errorType = e.getTypeName();
        String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        String stackTrace = e.getStackTraceString();

        if(errorType.equalsIgnoreCase('DmlException')){
            String outputLine1 = 'An exception of type '+errorType+' has occurred. Following are the details:';
            String outputLine2 = '\nError Message: '+errorMessage;
            String outputLine3 = '\nError Trace: '+stackTrace;

            System.debug(outputLine1+outputLine2+outputLine3);
        }else{
            throw new OVL_CustomException('An error has occured. Please call the ANZ IT Helpdesk with following error description: '+ e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ? If you didn't do it then i suggest you to refer this link : 
**1.**https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods                                                                                            **2.** https://salesforcenihar.blogspot.in/2015/07/test-class-example.html

Answer (score 5):

Testing exceptions has a bit of nuance to it, but it's not that much different from writing "regular" unit tests. You test it in much the same way as you test any other code, *by deliberately causing the code, that you're trying to test, to run* (and with varied inputs).

Your input here is an exception. While you can't construct a new instance of the generic `System.Exception` class, you can construct most (if not all) of the more specific exception classes (like `System.DmlException`).

Your output here is nothing testable in some cases (just writing lines to the log, which you may want to change to give you something to explicitly assert against), and a different exception in others.

Just like any other code, if you think there's a chance of an operation resulting in an exception, you should put it in a try/catch block.

For unit tests, such a block might look like this

```java
// This boolean variable will allow us to know whether or not we encountered
//   an exception.
Boolean exceptionThrown = false;
try{
    codeBeingTested.someMethod();
}catch (Exception e){
    // While using the generic Exception class will work, a unit test will be
    //   a lot more useful if you only catch specific exception types.
    // If you expect an OVL_CustomException, but get a System.MathException instead,
    //   then this test should fail so you have an indication that something isn't working
    //   the way you think it should
    exceptionThrown = true;
}finally{
    // A 'finally' block is one that is always run, regardless of whether or not 
    //   you entered the catch block.
    // That makes it a natural place to make an assertion against whether or not
    //   an exception was encountered.
    // Simply adjust the expected value to 'false' if you want to assert that
    //   an exception was not thrown (you probably also want to change the assertion
    //   failure message accordingly as well).
    system.assertEquals(true, exceptionThrown, 'Expected an exception to be thrown, but there was no exception');
}
```

As for what the rest of your test might look like, well, it's basically just a normal call to a static method

```
MyClass.handleExceptions(new System.DmlException());
```